# Angular - nicEdit validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation, rich-text-editor

I am using nicEdit as an editor in my Angular JS application. The following is the HTML and the script side.

```
<form>
<textarea name="area3" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;" required ng-model="description">

</textarea>
</form>


bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
```

In all other textboxes and textarea's there are angular invalid classes ( ng-invalid, ng-touched, ng-valid) showing, so that a red highlight is showing for invalid field.

My question is how to add these validation classes to the nicEditor which has been dynamically created.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try something like this in controller

```
$scope.nicEdit={description : ''};
```

and in view

```
<textarea name="area3" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;" required ng-model="nicEdit.description">
```

hopeItworks.. :)